# Split the Date and Year and format the date into standard MM/DD/YYYY in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working on date formatting and few cells contains data i.e. June/142017(no slash between date and year). I want to split the date and year and convert into standard format MM/DD/YYYY.

I'm formatting the date into standard format, which is becoming exclusive to June Month, by using the replace function, i.e. replace("June/142017", "June/14/2017"). Please, could you assist me with the code that should split and convert into standard format which is not specific.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
`import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
File = pd.read_excel("Final_file.xlsx")
LFile = File.replace("June/142017","June/14/2017")
LFile["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(LFile["Date"]).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
LFile.to_excel("Updated_Final_File.xlsx")`
```

*** FYI - I'm new to Python.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use format `%B/%d%Y` for match `June/142017`:

```
File = pd.read_excel("Final_file.xlsx")

d1 = pd.to_datetime(LFile["Date"], format='%B/%d%Y', errors='coerce')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(LFile["Date"], errors='coerce')

LFile["Date"] = d2.fillna(d1).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
LFile.to_excel("Updated_Final_File.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. My excel sheet contains data in other formats too. Example: 07-10-2015  00:00:00, 11/13.2015. I have tried to execute the code which was given by you but it is showing the error message(ValueError: time data '2015-10-07 00:00:00' does not match format '%B/%d%Y' (match)).

Comment: @Nani - can you test now? There are only 2 formats?

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. There are many formats jez. I'm working to identifying the unique cases .